# Just one row after using COUNT in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, count, group-by, aggregate-functions

Not sure why I am getting just one row with wrong count!

Following is the working code:

```
SELECT project_name, sub_project_name
FROM projects, sub_projects
WHERE projects.project_id = sub_projects.projects_project_id
```

Result:

```
project_name         sub_project_name
Bakken               Ghost fracture Study
Bakken               Bakken Mylo QAQC
Bossier              Doyle Boles K No.1
Eagleford            Kennedy Unit#1H
Eagleford            Wehmeyer Unit #1
Niobrara             Crow Valley 7-62-32-1M
Poland               Poland
Woodford             Ridenour Phase 2
Woodford             Teague 1-14H
```

Each sub_project has multiple tables and I am basically trying to see if a column in one of the tables has any row containing non-Null values and then show that count beside the sub_project in another column for each sub_project.

Here is what I get when I query the following statement:

```
SELECT projects.project_name, sub_projects.sub_project_name, COUNT( bl.bl_por ) AS porosity
FROM projects, sub_projects
LEFT JOIN bl ON sub_projects.sub_project_id = bl.sub_project_id
WHERE projects.project_id = sub_projects.projects_project_id
```

Result:

```
project_name         sub_project_name          porosity
Bakken               Ghost fracture Study      99
```

All the rows from every sub_project in the first row and nothing else.

Whats wrong here?

---

#### Edit:

Erwin's solution nailed it. But I do not have `sub_project_id` in my tables. I just added it in one table to make it simpler for testing.

So I used Erwin's `GROUP BY` suggestion to edit my statement and I get the right matrix shape but not the right counts. Counts are way off.

```
SELECT p.project_name, sp.sub_project_name, COUNT( bl.bl_por ) AS porosity
FROM projects p, sub_projects sp, wells w, cores c, samples s, inputs i
LEFT JOIN bl ON i.inputs_id = bl.inputs_inputs_id
WHERE p.project_id = sp.projects_project_id
AND s.sample_id = i.samples_sample_id
AND c.core_id = s.cores_core_id
AND sp.sub_project_id = c.sub_projects_has_wells_sub_projects_sub_project_id
GROUP BY p.project_name, sp.sub_project_name
```

Result:

```
project_name    sub_project_name        porosity
Bakken          Bakken Mylo QAQC        147
Bakken          Ghost fracture Study    252
Bossier         Doyle Boles K No.1      189
Eagleford       Kennedy Unit#1H         294
Eagleford       Wehmeyer Unit #1        0
Niobrara        Crow Valley 7-62-32-1M  0
Poland          Poland                  714
Woodford        Ridenour Phase 2        483
Woodford        Teague 1-14H            0
```

The correct result should be:

```
Bakken          Bakken Mylo QAQC        7
Bakken          Ghost fracture Study    12
Bossier         Doyle Boles K No.1      9
Eagleford       Kennedy Unit#1H         14
Eagleford       Wehmeyer Unit #1        0
Niobrara        Crow Valley 7-62-32-1M  0
Poland          Poland                  34
Woodford        Ridenour Phase 2        23
Woodford        Teague 1-14H            0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try an explicit `JOIN` condition and explicit `GROUP BY` (although mysql allows to skip on the later).

```
SELECT p.project_name, sp.sub_project_name, COUNT(bl.bl_por) AS porosity
FROM   projects p
JOIN   sub_projects sp ON p.project_id = sp.projects_project_id
LEFT   JOIN bl ON sp.sub_project_id = bl.sub_project_id
GROUP  BY p.project_name, sp.sub_project_name;
```

---

#### Answer to additional question:

Again, try proper SQL syntax whit explicit `JOIN` and join-conditions:

```
SELECT p.project_name, sp.sub_project_name, COUNT(bl.bl_por) AS porosity
FROM   projects p
JOIN   sub_projects sp ON p.project_id = sp.projects_project_id
JOIN   wells w -- no JOIN condition? Results in cross join.
JOIN   cores c ON sp.sub_project_id = c.sub_projects_has_wells_sub_projects_sub_project_id
JOIN   samples s ON c.core_id = s.cores_core_id
JOIN   inputs i ON s.sample_id = i.samples_sample_id
LEFT   JOIN bl ON i.inputs_id = bl.inputs_inputs_id
GROUP  BY p.project_name, sp.sub_project_name
```

This way you notice immediately that the table `wells` is joined in without unconditionally. This results in a **cross join**: every row of the left side is extended with every row on the right side, which produces **a lot** of rows. Probably the source of your excessive counts.

Also be aware that **count only counts non-null values**. Any row where bl.bl_por IS NULL is not counted. If you actually want to count the *number of rows*, you can use `count(bl.*)`.

Comment: I actually dont have that sub_project_id in the bl table. I have created non-identifying relationships and my data has a hierarchy. Its like projects->sub_projects->cores->samples->inputs and then all the other tables like bl, uss, ss, etc which have a foreign key in inputs table. inputs table has a foreign key in samples table and so on.. So the real question is using the above explicit method how can i use multible conditions in place of sp.sub_project_id = bl.sub_project_id to achive the relation?

Comment: @user1082783: It is good practice here to open a new question for a new question. People who find this page will have a hard time to figure out what it is all about. You can always add a link to this question for clarification.